# Count last entry by date and other column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm currently working on a statistic page and one of the table makes me struggle.

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| id | id_status | id_queue | datetime            | // Comments
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1         | 1        | 2021-07-01 17:03:13 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:1  for: #1#       (id_status: 1)
| 2  | 1         | 2        | 2021-07-01 17:03:18 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:2  for: #1#2#         (id_status: 1)
| 9  | 1         | 9        | 2021-07-01 17:03:45 |
| 10 | 1         | 10       | 2021-07-01 17:03:49 |
| 11 | 2         | 7        | 2021-07-01 17:04:10 |
| 12 | 3         | 7        | 2021-07-01 17:07:36 |
| 13 | 2         | 10       | 2021-07-01 17:07:54 |
| 14 | 3         | 10       | 2021-07-01 17:08:36 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:10 for: #1#       (id_status: 3)
| 15 | 2         | 9        | 2021-07-01 17:15:04 |
| 16 | 5         | 9        | 2021-07-01 17:15:24 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:9  for: #1#2#3#4# (id_status: 5)
| 18 | 3         | 7        | 2021-07-01 17:35:58 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:7  for: #1#       (id_status: 3)
//- -   -   -   - new day #2#  -    -   -   -   -   -   
| 19 | 2         | 7        | 2021-07-02 18:36:23 |
| 21 | 3         | 1        | 2021-07-02 18:39:49 |
| 22 | 14        | 1        | 2021-07-02 18:40:17 |
| 23 | 14        | 10       | 2021-07-02 18:40:17 |
| 24 | 2         | 1        | 2021-07-02 19:14:21 |
| 25 | 1         | 1        | 2021-07-02 19:14:32 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:1  for: #2#3#4#   (id_status: 1)
| 26 | 2         | 10       | 2021-07-02 19:14:35 |
| 27 | 1         | 10       | 2021-07-02 19:14:39 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:10 for: #2#3#4#   (id_status: 1)
| 28 | 1         | 7        | 2021-07-02 19:14:46 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:7  for: #2#3#4#   (id_status: 1)
//- -   -   -   - new day #3#  -    -   -   -   -   -   
| 31 | 2         | 2        | 2021-07-05 17:20:39 |
| 32 | 3         | 2        | 2021-07-05 17:24:59 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:2  for: #3#       (id_status: 3)
//- -   -   -   - new day #4#  -    -   -   -   -   -   
| 33 | 2         | 3        | 2021-07-06 09:38:03 |
| 34 | 3         | 3        | 2021-07-06 09:38:16 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:3  for: #4#       (id_status: 3)
| 35 | 2         | 6        | 2021-07-06 10:12:18 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:6  for: #4#       (id_status: 2)
| 37 | 2         | 2        | 2021-07-06 11:37:50 |
| 38 | 13        | 2        | 2021-07-06 12:02:19 |
| 39 | 2         | 2        | 2021-07-06 12:02:21 |
| 40 | 13        | 2        | 2021-07-06 12:04:12 | //<- last_entry: id_queue:2  for: #4#       (id_status: 13)
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I'm looking to get for each `%Y/%m/%d` the COUNT of each last entry until the current date of id_status from each id_queue.

Basically, for every day, it makes the count of the last entries based on the actual `datetime` column.

An example of the output based on the previous table above:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| id_status |  occurrences |  day       |  HELP_COLUMN(comment id from table above) |
+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| 1         | 2            | 2021-07-01 |  #1#                                      |
| 3         | 2            | 2021-07-01 |  #1#                                      |
| 5         | 1            | 2021-07-01 |  #1#                                      |
| 2         | 4            | 2021-07-02 |  #2#                                      |
| 5         | 1            | 2021-07-02 |  #2#                                      |
| 1         | 3            | 2021-07-05 |  #3#                                      |
| 3         | 1            | 2021-07-05 |  #3#                                      |
| 5         | 1            | 2021-07-05 |  #4#                                      |
| 1         | 3            | 2021-07-05 |  #4#                                      |
| 3         | 1            | 2021-07-05 |  #4#                                      |
| 2         | 1            | 2021-07-05 |  #4#                                      |
| 13        | 1            | 2021-07-05 |  #4#                                      |
+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

- For #1# (first day) take last entries of id_queue (based on
  max(datetime).
- For #2# (second day) take the last entries of id_queue
  (base on max(datetime)) (as you can see some of the last entries of
  id_queue are in the previous day). etc...

I tried multiple ways but I start to feel that this looks like it needs to be solved with an iterator... but I can't execute one SQL query by day this would cost too much performance.

Does someone know which SQL request I could use?
Tanks.

---

**Edit:** Here is another example:

**Input:**

```
+-----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| id  | id_status | id_queue |      datetime       |
+-----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|  61 |         5 |        1 | 2021-07-01 15:03:40 |
| 132 |         5 |        1 | 2021-07-01 16:39:13 |
|   1 |         1 |        1 | 2021-07-01 17:03:13 | <- last 1 :    1 #1#
|   2 |         1 |        2 | 2021-07-01 17:03:18 | <- last 2 :    1 #1#2#
|   3 |         1 |        3 | 2021-07-01 17:03:21 | <- last 3 :    1 #1#2#
|   4 |         1 |        4 | 2021-07-01 17:03:25 | <- last 4 :    1 #1#2#3#
|   5 |         1 |        5 | 2021-07-01 17:03:29 | <- last 5 :    1 #1#2#3#
|   6 |         1 |        6 | 2021-07-01 17:03:33 | <- last 6 :    1 #1#2#3#
|   7 |         1 |        7 | 2021-07-01 17:03:37 | 
|   8 |         1 |        8 | 2021-07-01 17:03:41 | <- last 8 :    1 #1#2#3#
|   9 |         1 |        9 | 2021-07-01 17:03:45 | 
|  10 |         1 |       10 | 2021-07-01 17:03:49 |
|  11 |         2 |        7 | 2021-07-01 17:04:10 |
|  12 |         3 |        7 | 2021-07-01 17:07:36 |
|  13 |         2 |       10 | 2021-07-01 17:07:54 |
|  14 |         3 |       10 | 2021-07-01 17:08:36 | <- last 10 :   3 #1#
|  15 |         2 |        9 | 2021-07-01 17:15:04 |
|  16 |         5 |        9 | 2021-07-01 17:15:24 | <- last 9 :    5 #1#2#3#
|  17 |         2 |        7 | 2021-07-01 17:35:36 |
|  18 |         3 |        7 | 2021-07-01 17:35:58 | <- last 7 :    3 #1#
|  19 |         2 |        7 | 2021-07-02 18:36:23 |
|  20 |         2 |        1 | 2021-07-02 18:36:39 |
|  21 |         3 |        1 | 2021-07-02 18:39:49 |
|  23 |        14 |       10 | 2021-07-02 18:40:17 |
|  22 |        14 |        1 | 2021-07-02 18:40:17 |
|  24 |         2 |        1 | 2021-07-02 19:14:21 |
|  25 |         1 |        1 | 2021-07-02 19:14:32 | <-- last 1 :   1 #2#3#
|  26 |         2 |       10 | 2021-07-02 19:14:35 |
|  27 |         1 |       10 | 2021-07-02 19:14:39 | <-- last 10 :  1 #2#3#
|  28 |         1 |        7 | 2021-07-02 19:14:46 | <-- last 7 :   1 #2#3#
|  29 |         2 |        3 | 2021-07-05 15:26:27 |
|  30 |         3 |        3 | 2021-07-05 15:26:48 | <--- last 3 :  3 #3#
|  31 |         2 |        2 | 2021-07-05 17:20:39 |
|  32 |         3 |        2 | 2021-07-05 17:24:59 | <--- last 2 :  3 #3#
+-----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

**#1 (2021-07-01):**

- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1    (7 occurences)
- 3,3              (2 occurences)
- 5                    (1 occurences)

**#2 (2021-07-02):** : https://i.ibb.co/vDhL05q/sublime-text-or-MEzs-GFh-Q.jpg

- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1    (9 occurences)
- 5                    (1 occurrences)

**#3 (2021-07-05):**

- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1        (7 occurrences)
- 3,3              (2 occurrences)
- 5                    (1 occurences)

**Output:**

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id_status |  occurences |     day    |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|         1 |           7 | 2021-07-01 |
|         3 |           2 | 2021-07-01 |
|         5 |           1 | 2021-07-01 |
|         1 |           9 | 2021-07-02 |
|         5 |           1 | 2021-07-02 |
|         1 |           7 | 2021-07-05 |
|         3 |           2 | 2021-07-05 |
|         5 |           1 | 2021-07-05 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed by writing this query:

I'm sure it can be optimized and can be reduced to fewer sub-queries, if anybody has an idea, I would be happy to select another answer as "resolving answer"

```
SELECT id_status, COUNT(entries_status.id_status) as occurrences, entries_status.day
FROM (
    SELECT history.id_status, history.id_queue, last_entries.day
    FROM history
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT id_queue, max(datetime) last_entry_of_day, day
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM history
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT date(datetime) AS day
                FROM `history`
                GROUP BY date(datetime)) as days
                ON date(history.datetime) <= days.day
                ORDER BY datetime ASC) entries
            GROUP BY id_queue, day
    ) as last_entries
    ON history.id_queue = last_entries.id_queue AND
history.datetime = last_entries.last_entry_of_day) as entries_status
GROUP BY entries_status.day, entries_status.id_status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date(datetime) as day, id_status, count(*) as occurrences
from (
  select *,row_number() over (partition by date(datetime),id_queue order by datetime desc) rn 
  from tablename
) t where rn = 1
group by date(datetime) , id_status
order by date(datetime) , id_status
```

this query sort rows in each day and for the same id_queue and gives them a row number order by latest ones first and chooses the first one  ( rn = 1) so you have latest unique id_queue in each day and then you group by and count number of queu_ids

Comment: Hello @eshirvana, thank you for your answer,

Could you please detail how it works?

There is still an issues, there is missing entries.

I tested it on my table: 
The first day total => 10 (number of differents id_queue)
But the second day only 3 are present.

Comment: @MathiasOsterhagen hmm....It should have worked. for the data sample you provided it works. edit your question and the data that this query didn't work and show your expected output for them

Comment: I just updated my question.
Thank you again to help me, with your query, I got missing lines (here is the result: @eshirvana, I just updated my question.
With your query I got missing lines (here is the result: https://pastebin.com/raw/kLPcfJkU )

Comment: @MathiasOsterhagen for day #2 (2021-07-02) , all the selected id_queue have  id_status =1 , why in output you have id_status = 5 ? even for id_status = 1  the occurrence for that day is 3 times why 9 times ? i'm not following your logic

Comment: Hello @eshirvana.

Check `line 16` you see the `#2#` and the `id_status = 5`.
You have it in fact nine time because it counts all from beginning.
Like `<= current_date`.

To count it you start from the bottom then mark the occurrences of the current day like #1 ou #2, to make it cleared copy paste it in a text editor like sublime text and search for #2 like that: https://i.ibb.co/vDhL05q/sublime-text-or-MEzs-GFh-Q.jpg . It is like taking every day the last entry from `datetime <= current day`. Thank you for your help

Comment: @MathiasOsterhagen then why it didn't happen for the next day (2021-07-05)?

Comment: it happened normaly. 
If you check this picture as well (I research for #3) all last entries for `datetime <= '2021-07-05'`:  https://i.ibb.co/cr4JzSX/sublime-text-Q5-Wo-Gv-LUMX.jpg

Comment: let me know if I can add more precisions :s.